# Sequelize: how to pass findAll result as Model.create value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to insert an entry into table "Message" by passing an ID from table "Users" to use as an entry value but I'm getting a "val.replace is not a function error". Here is my code:

```
Message.create({
  userId:
    Users.findAll({
      where: { username: "sam123" },
      attributes: ['id'],
      plain: true
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.id)
      return result.id
    }),
  roomname: 'lobby',
  message: 'testing'
})
```

My console log is returning the correct ID number but it is not passing that number to "userId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use async/await and first find a user and then create a message OR
create a message in `then` callback.
By the way, is your `userId` contains an array of user ids? Because `Users.findAll` returns an array of objects.

The first solution:

```
// here we get first user that satisfies our condition
const foundUser = await Users.findOne({
      where: { username: "sam123" },
      attributes: ['id'],
      plain: true
    })
await Message.create({
  userId: foundUser.id,
  roomname: 'lobby',
  message: 'testing'
})
```

The second solution

```
// here we get first user that satisfies our condition
Users.findOne({
      where: { username: "sam123" },
      attributes: ['id'],
      plain: true
    }).then((result) => {
  Message.create({
    userId: result.id,
    roomname: 'lobby',
    message: 'testing'
})
})
```

Make sure you found at least one user otherwise add a check for that.